# Reload Activity on click on NavigationBar Back Button

Tags: android, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I am using MikePenz Material Drawer to build a drawer in my xamarin application. So far it works great. 
URL : [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

All my activities are inherited from a BaseActivity, and within this base activity I have initiated the drawer plugin.

But, when I click on the back arrow in the toolbar, I need to reload the previous activity. At the moment it loads that activity but the data is not refreshed.

I have overriden the below method for the back button. But what I need to know is how can I start an activity depending on which page its called from.

```
public bool OnNavigationClickListener (View clickedView)
    {
        this.Finish();
        return true;
    }
```

**Note** : The above method is in the base activity.

Comment: Is there a difficulty in updating date in onResume() of previous activity? I am sure that onResume of the visible activity will be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your logics in **onResume()** of previous activity.

I am sure that onResume of the visible activity will be called.

Cheers,
Sha

Answer (score 1):

Activities sit in a stack, so when you call finish() it is actually just popping this off of the stack and showing you what is left in the stack. However, it is your responsibility to invalidate the cache at that point. So whatever you are binding to, i.e. an adapter of some sort or your activity view, should be invalidated.